# How to set Chrome as default browser via cmd/script on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, cmd.exe

In my work laptop, there are few restrictions imposed organisation wide and one of them is to disallow setting a default browser. I'm tired of all my links opening in stupid IE. I just want every link to open in chrome instead. I'm a developer and I have to open close to 2000 external a day and it is insanely irritating to copy link manually to chrome again and again.

I do have admin privileges on my laptop so I can do stuff via cmd. Please tell me if there is an alternative script to set default browser via command line.

Chrome: v79
IE: v11
OS: Windows 7

PS: This is NOT a duplicate question.

Comment: [How to Set a Default Web Browser in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/352167/how-to-set-a-default-web-browser-in-windows/)

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-file-associations-windows10/ and https://commandwindows.com/assoc.htm